# What is the preferred way to install Viber in a 21.10 desktop environment

Tags: viber, snap-store

In my previous ubuntu installs I've downloaded a deb for 12.04 from the viber website. From there I have needed to install some dependencies; not a biggie.  But now I'm seeing viber in the snap store.  I'm thinking cool, this should be easy.

"viber-unofficial" snap is missing a dependency on glibc 2.33. I thought snaps would include their dependecies.
"viber-mtd" - Viber desktop support ubuntu. Doesn't seem to be doing anything.

When I try to install the deb from the viber website, I get the message "not supported" in the snap store application.

I'm running gnome. 21'10 flavor.

Comment: Are you downloading the deb then opening it with Ubuntu Software or telling the browser to automatically open it? The latter is unfortunately no longer supported.

Comment: Indeed that was my MO. I downloaded the deb from viber.com. I had to install libgstreamer but now it works fine.   I still think the question stands. 2 bad packages in the repo. One is a snap with unmet dependencies.

Comment: You're right but also there's a reason why it has "unofficial" in the name ;)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yeah but still I'd like to trust the software center/snap store

Comment: Snaps are indeed supposed to include dependencies. Please file a bug report with the Snap author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three [download](https://www.viber.com/en/download/) options:

1. AppImage from https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.AppImage
2. deb-file from https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
3. [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.viber.Viber) to install with the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install flatpak
   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
   ```

I find traditional deb-based method preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the recommendations from Viber webpage and it worked.

Then I had problem with the screen size, because the letters (fonts) were very tiny on the screen of my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa). After long time troubleshooting finally I found the right application file to edit.
You need to modify the line in the viber.desktop file and set the resolution to your screen, adjust the value, it can be any small like 0.5 or anything higher like 1.5:

```
exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=**1.1** /opt/viber/Viber %u
```

There Viber.desktop files can be found at 2 places:

- `/usr/share/applications/`
- `/home/username/.local/share/applications`

When I edited the 1st file nothing happened.
When I edited the .local file, it changed to correct resolution!
**So set QT_SCALE_FACTOR to a good value in `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications`**.